# Can I use dehumidifier to tackle mouldy bathroom

Tags: bathroom, mold, dehumidifier

we had a new bathroom built as an extension about 20 years ago. It didn't have any wallpaper or anything on it for a while, just the exposed brown plaster. It was painted using water based paint a few years ago. Since then it has become very mouldy. The bathroom is very rarely used. I thought of buying a dehumidifier to try and dry out the bathroom and stop the mould reproducing. Is this a good idea? Would the plaster itself be in good condition or would I have to get the room re plastered? I am slightly worried about getting mould in the dehumidifier as it collects the water in a tray.

Comment: The dehumidifier will help, but it isn't the solution to your problems. There's an underlying reason that moisture is collecting and not evaporating quickly enough. Please include more information and any pictures that you think could help us. We've never been to your house so we don't know what your bathroom looks like, etc. Did the problem start only when you painted? or did you do additional work at that time? Do you have an exhaust fan? Did you use mold-resistant/wet location drywall? Are the walls properly insulated?

Comment: I think the extension was a poor build. My dad thinks they cut the water feed to the shower far too short or something so it keeps leaking even when not in use I think. The toilet is also not fixed to the floor solidly so water trickles out of it onto the floor. I'll get some pics for you shortly.

Comment: The #1 thing will be to fix the leaks, _then_ tackle everything else. The humidifier will help as a band aid until you get to it this weekend (or maybe next), but it's not going to be anything of a long-term solution.

Comment: Oh ok, so I will look to get the shower replaced before I use a dehumidifier. Would the plaster be okay or does mould destroy it?

Comment: I'm guessing that the plaster used wasn't the kind usually used for bathrooms...as the bathroom kind is water/mold resistant.  You'll probably have to tear out a decent-sized area of plaster to get at all the pipes to make sure they were done correctly anyhow, so there's probably no use trying to save it. No telling how much water damage there is if it truly has been leaking for 20-odd years, so I think, at this point you have to open it all up to see what's going on in there.

Comment: And when you replaster, fit a tasteful cabinet door there that you can open to get full access to the piping and shower and tub spigot plumbing. Seen a lot in USA Victorian architecture, gee, where would we have gotten that from? ;) Feel free to steal the idea back!

Answer (score 0):

I would do several things at the same time.
To stop the mold you need to take the moisture away.
So a dehumidifier will take the moisture out of the air as the air is dryer the surfaces off gas more moisture making it harder or impossible for the mold to grow.

I would also spray any surface with 3% hydrogen peroxide and water.
If you have really large areas of mound higher percentages of hydrogen peroxide can be used don’t spray above 5% and at 8% it will start bleaching everything.
I use a sponge in some cases a long nap paint roller.
Plaster is one of the surfaces I have found horrid surface mold that was killed with 5% we had planned to gut that bathroom but it cleaned up well and there were no soft spots so we sealed the surround and the house sold without having to redo the bathroom (we did add an exhaust fan).

Comment: If the pipes are bad, that needs to be fixed first. You can't "dehumidify" a hole in the pipe.